# Proving that quotient map $\pi : X\rightarrow Y$ is invariant under action of finite algebraic group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm currently studying a little bit of algebraic geometry, especially algebraic groups and quotients. In J. Harris book "Algebraic Geometry" (http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/aconstant/Alg2/Bib/Harris_AlgebraicGeometry.pdf), he wants to prove on page 124 that the quotient of a finite group $G$ acting on an affine variety $X$ exists. For that, he first off constructs a variety $Y$ that satisfies $A(Y) = A(X)^G$. Since we have the natural inclusion $A(Y) = A(X)^G \rightarrow A(X)$, this induces a morphism $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$.

Now I was wondering: According to the definition of the quotient, one has to verify that $\pi$ is surjective, and that $\pi(x) = \pi(y) \iff \exists g \in G$ s.t. $x=g(y)$. However, it seems like he only proved surjectivity and only the "$\implies$" direction of the "$\iff$" statement. Is that already enough? Does this already imply that $\pi(x) = \pi(g(x))$, or is his proof missing some details? If yes, how can this be shown?

Comment: Shouldn't this follow from the definition of $A(Y)$ as $A(X)^G$? That is, all regular functions on $Y$ pull back to $G$-invariant ones on $X$, so in particular they must take the same value on $G$-orbits and you're done.